# what kind of internet filtering can I do with DD-WRT?

Tags: router, dd-wrt

I want to filter websites etc., can DD-WRT help me with this?

I will be signing up with openDNS also, but curious what I can do at the router level with DD-WRT?

if you can link to DD-WRT doc's that would be perfect!

1. can I block certain urls?
2. can I block internet access by Mac for certain timings?
3. can I log urls visited?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hosts file to DNSMasq.  I use an edited version of [this hosts file](http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/) on my Tomato router.